# How to replace /\ with \ in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
var str = "/\test\test1\test.jpg";
```

How to replace `/\` with `\` in JavaScript?

Comment: If you define your `str` like this, `\t` will be a tab character. Do you define the string yourself or do you process input? Those would be 2 different problems...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](https://i.imgur.com/3ppJhiE.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should escape `\` character with additional `\`. And there is the same rule for `/` in regular expressions.

```js
var str = "/\\test\\test1/\\test.jpg";
console.log('str is', str);

var res = str.replace(/\/\\/g, '\\')
console.log('res is', res);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var str = "/\test\test1\test.jpg";
var str = str.replace("//\", "/\");
```

Comment: That will not work! Backslash is a special escape character, so `"/\", "\"` is actually a  string with `/", ` followed by a literal `"`.... You need to escape the backslash in a literal string: `"/\\", "\\"`.

Comment: This will replace just the first occur of /\.

Comment: @dizel3d It will not even do that. The only thing you get it "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"